# Facebook API - Posting to Users Wall

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am building a small app that authenticates a user with Facebook. After the user is authenticated he can upload an image. Once this image is uploaded it has to be approved by our staff. The image might be approved days later. My concern is in regards to the access token. Once the image is approved I want to be able post to that users wall even if it's days later. What kind of issues should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the current expiration period for FB access token is 60 days if the image is being approved after 60 days and the use haven't authorized during that period, you have no option to post.

Comment: Great info! Thanks! So should I store the access token in the db when the user authenticates and then reference it later?

Comment: That also means i should ask for offline_access when i request permissions right? Just making sure i got this straight.

Comment: no, offline_access permission is now deprecated, here are some scenarios and methods how can you use access tokens: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook is [removing the old offline_access](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) permission and thus normal access tokens will only live for 1 or 2 hours, you will see a "deprecate offline_access" migration (enabled by default) in the app setting's advanced tab (the removal will take place [2012 October 3](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)). They introducing a [new endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token) that will let you extend the lifetime of the default short lived access tokens. If you want to be more future proof, you might want to migrate to this now.

Comment: In order to be future proof i should also be using Server-side OAuth instead of client-side right? Is that when I will get the 60 days?

Comment: In my understanding there's no distinction of the access tokens generated by exchanging the server side's "code" to access token (the code is short lived), or the one that generated by the client side and sent down with cookies to the server side.